# AWS having a cloudwatch alarm trigger cloudwatch insight query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, insight

I have a number of cloudwatch insight queries I would like to execute when certain metrics cross an alarm threshold. For example, when my service is being impacted, I would use insight queries to analyze which customers were impacted. Right now, I'm using cloudwatch alarm to trigger a lambda that is executing this query, but is there a more direct way?